# I am trying to count how many x are in a row but if there are blanks between sets of xs then it would start a second count - GoogleSheets

Tags: google-sheets, countif

On Google Sheets - I am trying to count how many x are in a row but if there are blanks between sets of xs then it would start a second count

The headers are dates, except for a description header

If my row has x on monday x on tuesday x on wednesday blanks for the next 3 days and then an x on sunday - I want the count for xs to be broken into two sets 3 and 1 instead of counting 4 for the whole row.  This can be over a multi-month period.

Or if it can't count that way then if it is possible to split rows when there is a space between x's and create a new row with the remaining x's and both rows include the description columns with

I have tried countifs

[image: Example]

In the first row I want the count to be 9, in the second row I want the count to be 3 and 5 - I want to restart the count everytime there is a blank.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1feu2YGNaM5SBBpdZLLWrKgVtg14ECfYfmyXtG1oslFE/edit?usp=sharing

I would like it to either count out to the right like I have on the first tab, or create a table like the second tab and give me the counts per type.  If I need to change the x's and blanks to another thing I can like 0s and 1s

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Please make your example text-based. Sharing an editable example is one such approach.

Comment: is this a candidate for the use of the [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)

Comment: `I want the count for xs to be broken into two sets 3 and 1 instead of counting 4 for the whole row.` As requested, please supply data NOT in an image, but also supply multiple rows of day data. Also include an example of example9s) of successful outcome(s).

Comment: `but if there are blanks between sets of xs then it would start a second count` Could there be multiple sequences of blanks, so that it might start a third, fourth, fifth,  etc count?

Comment: Yes there could be multiple sequences of blanks; there could be a third, fourth, fifth count  - I will add data

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1feu2YGNaM5SBBpdZLLWrKgVtg14ECfYfmyXtG1oslFE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   BYROW(B2:AF,
     LAMBDA(row,
       IF(COUNTA(row)=0,,
          LEN(SPLIT(JOIN(,IF(row="",0,"|")),0))))))
```

For each row, the formula is converting all the empty values in the row with `0` and all the non-empty values with `|`, then it's joining them using the [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) function and splitting them by the `0` using the [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) function. Finally, it takes the length of the resulting array using the [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en) function.

**Note:** This formula will only work if your range doesn't span across more than 50000 columns.

Comment: This is great - I appreciate it.  The only thing it is doing though which I can work around it if there is not a formula solution is on a row where I only had blanks it counted all the blanks, which I would just like no count on that since there are no Xs in that row

Comment: please replicate the issue in tab 'z' of the sample sheet.

Comment: I added a new sheet with an example - when I did it in your sheet it was working right but when I do the formula in my sheet it is giving the 41 count on the empty rows

Comment: those cells are not actually blank. If you run `ISBLANK()` it returns `FALSE`, you can select the range and clear it or replace `COUNTA(row)=0` with `COUNTBLANK(row)=COLUMNS(row)`